# Comparing list of objects to another list with objects using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I may be going about this the wrong way. I've loaded two csv documents with names of companies into a list and I'm trying to compare the two lists to find where names are similar.

The names have been lower cased and punctuation removed, but sometimes people entering the information abbreviate company identities or misspell a word, so I'm trying to find a way to assign a score based upon how similar the name are.

Original data might look something like this (not actual data):

```
Walgreens Boots Alliance
CARDINAL HEALTH
EXPRESS SCRIPTS HOLDING
j.p. morgan chase
Bank of America Corp
wells fargo
Home Depot
STATE FARM INSURANCE COS.
Johnson & Johnson
archer daniels midland
```

Then lower casing, removing stopwords/punctuation, and splitting:

```
[walgreens, boots, alliance]
[cardinal, health]
[express, scripts, holding]
[jp, morgan, chase]
[bank, america, corp]
[wells, fargo]
[home, depot]
[state, farm, insurance, cos]
[johnson, johnson]
[archer, daniels, midland]
```

... and a similar second list would look something like this:

```
[cardinal, health]
[expres, scripts, holding]
[bank, america, corporation]
[wells, fargo]
[home, depot]
[state, farm, insurance, companies]
[archer, daniels]
[ford, motor, company]
[general, motors]
[john, deere]
```

I've written a convoluted loop for Pandas to test if each word in the list also exists in the other lists:

```
for index, row in df1[['Company Name Tokens']].iterrows():
    for content in row:
        for x in content:
            df1.iloc[index]['Test'] = 0
            df1.iloc[index]['Count'] = len(content)
            for idx, rw in entities[['Company Name Tokens']]:
                for r in rw:
                    if x in r:
                        df1.iloc[index]['Test'] = df1.iloc[index]['Test'] + 1
```

I realize this is likely really slow, but I'm not after efficiency. Regardless, I think that this approach might be too much for the Python interpreter to handle since I got an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-adea96d8cb82> in <module>()
      4             df1.iloc[index]['Test'] = 0
      5             df1.iloc[index]['Count'] = len(content)
----> 6             for idx, rw in entities[['Company Name Tokens']]:
      7                 for r in rw:
      8                     if x in r:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Am I making this too difficult and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This 'naive' approach will always be slow. You want to use some better data structure like inverted index - create a dictionary of words containing a list of row numbers where the word is found .. or something alike, depending on your final task.

Comment: @liborm interesting... so something like {'archer': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'daniels': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'midland': []}?

Comment: You need to specify your task more to get at least a suggestion for a data structure or an algorithm.. But in general yes - process one of the data sets into the index, and scan through the other looking up words one by one in the index.

Comment: @liborm or maybe like a matrix, with the first column just the words and the other columns indicating which rows they show up? {'archer': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'daniels': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'midland': [0, 0, 0, 0]}?

Answer (score 0):

If you just have the two lists to begin with you could get the union of sets for each list:

```
shared = set(list_a).union(set(list_b))
```

You will just need the two lists to be 1-D instead of 2-D as the DataFrames are. Granted this will only work when the data is entered in a standard fashion. Your gonna have to clean the two for any errors in entry as you mentioned.